# Use Regex to match beginning and end part of URL in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm looking for a regex function to implement in a goal for Google Analytics.

Consider this URL:  `/dagje-uit/....variable part..../contact/vpv/bedankt`

Regex should work when beginning of URL matches `/dagje-uit/` and end part contains `/contact/vpv/bedankt` Everything in the middle can be variable.

Without result i've tried

`(?=^/dagje-uit/.*)(?=.*/bedankt$).*`

`(?=^dagje-uit.*)(?=.*bedankt$).*`

Thanks in advance! 
Regards,
Pim

Comment: You can try `^/dagje-uit/.*/bedankt$` or `^/dagje-uit/.*/contact/vpv/bedankt$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me if Google Analytics has some regex standards which I am overlooking but is it possible that your regex is failing because it does not account for the start of the whole of the URL? Adding `.*` to either end of your regex may help.

It also looks like your regex is over-complex for the conditions you have described. Could a simpler match be :

`.*/dagje-uit/.*/contact/vpv/bedankt.*`

or

`http(s)?://.*/dagje-uit/.*/contact/vpv/bedankt.*`

if you want to be a little more confident that it is a valid URL.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for the super quick responses. Both options work, but I am going to implement the one from Joe since the .* gives a bit more flexibility. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem Pim. Can I recommend an application called Regex Coach if you are going to do any regex work at all! It removes any doubt you may have in the regex you are writing and is incredibly quick and easy to use http://the-regex-coach.en.softonic.com/